# How to show only event appearing rows in FullCalendar.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am using `FullCalendar` v3.9.0 and need to show `rows` if it has any events only for `week` and `day` view. Pleas see the below image:

[image]

As you can see, above calendar showing rows of 8 AM to 12 PM. but it only has events from 9 to 11 AM. Thus I just want to show calendar from 9 AM to 11 AM.

I have tried it using `filterResourcesWithEvents: true,` but it didnt worked. Please see my code below:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: '',
        center: 'prev, title, next',
        right: 'today, month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
    },
    views: {
        agendaWeek: {
            columnHeaderFormat:  'ddd D/M',
        }
    },
    minTime: "08:00:00", //I have tried by commenting this as well.
    maxTime: "23:00:00", //I have tried by commenting this as well.
    defaultDate: output,
    filterResourcesWithEvents: false,
    slotEventOverlap : false,
    contentHeight: 2000,
    navLinks: false, 
    editable: false,
    eventLimit: true, 
    height: "auto",
    events: course_data,
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek'
});
```

Looking hopefully to have some suggestions or answer, Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, filterResourcesWithEvents should be set to true, in your code it is set to false.

Comment: I have checked with both values but it is not working @KhurramIshaque

Comment: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/issues/98

Comment: I have already checked this link and implemented mentioned but it didn't worked

Comment: filterResourcesWithEvents has nothing to do with this. Time slots are not resources.

Comment: Anyway you can't hide empty times slots like you're suggesting. It breaks the concept of the grid (and would break the concept of dragging and dropping, or selecting areas to add new events, if you had got those enabled.

Comment: If you just want to see events without empty spaces between them, then maybe the [basic view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/basic-view) or [list view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/list-view) would suit you better.

Comment: P.S. If you know for sure that there will only ever be events starting between 9am and 11am, then you could try sticking with the agenda view and amending `minTime` and `maxTime` to restrict the times on display. But it's only useful if your time range is predictable every day.